# External SQLite database in JavaScript/ JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite

I wonder is there any way to use external (my own) SQLite database using JavaScript/ JQuery in a website? Any good examples? I have already done some search but cannot find any good article!

Answer (score 0):

No. JavaScript runs client side there is no way to provision this outside of the client sandbox environment.

There is work being done in this area in a controlled form, such as: http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/